# TypeScript Types conflict with graphql types

Tags: typescript, graphql, codegen

I have a GraphQL resolver and schema that look like this:

```js
import { Resolvers } from "../../generated/schema";

export const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getS: async (_parent: unknown, { id }: { id: string }): Promise<GenericResponse<S>> => { ... }
    }
}
```

and

```
type Query {
  getS(id: ID!): getSResponse
}

type S {
  id: ID!,
  wac: Float!,
  beginDate: String!,
  endDate: String!,
}

type getSResponse implements GenericResponse {
  status: Status!
  data: S!
}
```

I'm using GraphQL codegen to check types for resolver functions with the following contents:

```js
export type Resolvers<ContextType = any> = {
  Query?: QueryResolvers<ContextType>;
}

export type QueryResolvers<ContextType = any, ParentType extends ResolversParentTypes['Query'] = ResolversParentTypes['Query']> = {
getS?: Resolver<Maybe<ResolversTypes['getSResponse']>, ParentType, ContextType, RequireFields<QueryGetSArgs, 'id'>>;
}

export type QueryGetSArgs = {
  id: Scalars['ID']['input'];
};

export type Scalars = {
  ID: { input: string | number; output: string; }
  String: { input: string; output: string; }
  Boolean: { input: boolean; output: boolean; }
  Int: { input: number; output: number; }
  Float: { input: number; output: number; }
};
```

However, I am getting this typescript error:

```js
Type '(_parent: unknown, { id }: myType) => Promise<GenericResponse<S>>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper<GetWacPercentageResponse>>, {}, any, RequireFields<QueryGetSArgs, "id">> | undefined'.
  Type '(_parent: unknown, { id }: myType) => Promise<GenericResponse<S>>' is not assignable to type 'ResolverFn<Maybe<ResolverTypeWrapper<GetSResponse>>, {}, any, RequireFields<QueryGetSArgs, "id">>'.
    Types of parameters '__1' and 'args' are incompatible.
      Type 'RequireFields<QueryGetSArgs, "id">' is not assignable to type 'myType'.
        Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
          Type 'NonNullable<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID can apparently be a `string` or `number`:

```
  ID: { input: string | number; output: string; }
```

But your resolver argument has it strongly typed to a `string` which TS correctly points out as an issue because that resolver can receive a number as per your scalar definition of `ID`. You need to make that work with `string` or `number`

```
getS: async (_parent: unknown, { id }: { id: string | number }): Promise<GenericResponse<S>> => { ... }
```

But to be honest, since you already assign `Resolvers` type to the whole `resolvers` object you should just be able to completely remove the inline types and it will be inferred:

```
getS: async (_parent, { id }) => { ... } // `id` should automatically be inferred as string | number
```

Comment: thank you so much for this! I unfortunately have to strongly type everything per the TS lint rules defined in our `.eslintrc` file so the first option best suits my scenario.

Comment: Those are very bad and crazy linting rules! It's often the case sadly that many of these rules available in typescript-eslint are complete nonsense. It's total madness to opt out of inference. In this instance, 0 extra type safety is offered by doing this since its already typed in Resolvers and will also lead to more obtuse errors. It will also make refactoring harder. Basically, no benefit whatsoever and a time waster.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
type Query {
  getS(id: ID!): getSResponse
}
```

Saying `getS` would accept `id` of type `ID = number or string`. But your resolver implementation goes like

```
Query: {
    getS: async (_parent: unknown, { id }: { id: string }): Promise<GenericResponse<S>> => { ... }
}
```

saying it would ONLY take `id` of type `string`.

Obviously there’s a contradiction here. You probably want to change your resolver param to `{ id: string | number }`.